# ios9 custom action on nav back button

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios9

From my understanding in order to follow apples standard nav design there cannot be custom actions performed when the back button is pressed since the back button is no longer configured by the programer. However there are several cases where i would like to invoke some actions when the back button is pressed. For example send out network requests & setup some globals. What is a reliable means of executing code only when the back button is pressed?